# How to change password of one of the user on Postgres (Docker)?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I cloned the [program](https://github.com/zubroide/gitpab) which use PHP, Postgres and Docker and already runned it in my server. The admin details hardcoded in the code:

```
$name = 'admin';
$email = 'admin@admin';
$password = Hash::make('admin');

/** @var EloquentUserService $userService */
$userService = app(AppServiceProvider::ELOQUENT_USER_SERVICE);

/** @var \App\User $user */
$user = $userService->create([
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
]);
DB::commit();
```

How can I change this username/password using CLI inside the container?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name changed.

Comment: How would you do this without Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze I used docker-compose for install/run it in server. The admins creds hardcoded in php, and it creates the admin acount using that creds during installation. Now I want to change the admin creds in postgres.